# Specified cast is not valid with GetFloat on SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I have a database column called EarlyHoursStartTime which is declared as float.

Then I have some code where I loop through the whole table with a DataReader

```
SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while (myReader.Read())
{

    cmdInsertLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EarlyHoursStartTime", myReader.GetFloat(44)); <- Error here


}
```

I'm getting an error on the AddwithValues line above.

**"Specified cast is not valid."**

myReader.GetValue(44) is showing a value of 0.0 when this happens.

I'm tried all sorts of things to get around this like putting in a default value instead if:

```
if (Convert.ToString(myReader.GetValue(44)) == "0.0")
```

but this should be unnecessary and it's not working anyway.

Why am I getting an invalid cast exception when the value is 0.0? The database field read in by the datareader is Float, so what's the problem?

Comment: I think you should be using `GetDouble` as equivalent of [SQL float is double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @V4Vendetta that seems to have solved the problem. Do you want to put that into an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 9):

As per the [Mapping list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
SQL Server data type CLR data type (SQL Server) CLR data type (.NET Framework)
float                SqlDouble                  Double
```

the SQL float maps to the double datatype, so you should try using `GetDouble` instead of `GetFloat`

Answer (score 0):

why not try

```
float _float = Convert.ToSingle(myReader[FloatCol].tostring());
```

I dont tent tend to use Oridnal locations as i find converting everything renders less problem (most of the time)

regards